# iPhone 6 UIWebView select drop down issue

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, select, uiwebview

My iPhone app uses a UIWebView interface to launch local HTML/JavaScript pages.  It worked perfectly 'til the advent of iPhone 6.  Both the 6 and the 6+ render the pages correctly, but pages with a  form element seem broken.  Tapping the selector fails to bring up the traditional option picker at the bottom of the screen.

I've tried Xcode 6 iOS 8 base SDK builds with targets ranging from iOS 5 to 8, and the problem persists.  All simulators from 5S (iOS 8) and down work fine, but 6 and 6+ have the selector problem.

Also tried a Cordova build with no improvement.  And no luck adding onmouseover="" to the select element:

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I think its related to this issue [iOS8 cordova issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712148/ios8-cordova-issue) and it link to the cordova bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7694

The cordova bug says that its a ios bug...  So I wonder why it still allowed to use this technique, at least we should be warned big time to **not use SELECT elements**.

Still looking for a patch or a workaround...

[UPDATE] The "presentViewController" code in my [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26716940/2152973) works !

Answer (score 0):

Are you just using the iOS simulator to test this? I had a similar issue in the simulator, but testing it on an actual device seemed to work fine for me. However, in iOS Simulator, try going to Hardware -> Keyboard, and uncheck 'Connect Hardware Keyboard'.